# How to call confirm dialog on button Yii2 Action column?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I am using Kartik/grid. I have this button in action column.How can I have a confirm dialog on clicking it, like in delete ?

```
 [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template'=>'{statement}',
                'controller'=>'statement',
                'buttons'  => [
                    'pay' => function($url,$model) {

                              if($model->sum_balance<>0) {
                                return Html::a('Statement', $url, ['class'=>'pay btn btn-primary','data-pjax' => '0']);
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }                          
                    },

                ]
            ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hii Kritika555,

```
                'buttons'  => [
                'pay' => function($url,$model) {

                          if($model->sum_balance<>0) {
                            return Html::a('Statement', $url, ['onClick' => 'return confirm("You'r confirmation message?")', 'class'=>'pay btn btn-primary','data-pjax' => '0']);
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }                          
                },

            ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Mohan's answer is correct, in Yii2 there is a much more simpler way of making a confirm popup for your buttons or links. Just add data-confirm="Your question here" as a property to any button or a link you want to trigger a confirm box.

```
                'buttons'  => [
            'pay' => function($url,$model) {

                      if($model->sum_balance<>0) {
                        return Html::a('Statement', $url, ['data-confirm'=>"Your confirmation message?", 'class'=>'pay btn btn-primary','data-pjax' => '0']);
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }                          
            },

        ]
```